# Using fluid in Javascript code work and no work in same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I am using a fluid variable inside Javascript code in a Fluid Template. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#{element.uniqueIdentifier}').datetimepicker();
    /*Call AJAX*/
    $('#{element.uniqueIdentifier}').change(function (event) {
      .... //Other code lines
    });
  });
</script>
```

The HTML rendered is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  $('#solicituddeAuditorios-repeatablecontainer-1_0_datetimepicker-2').datetimepicker();
  /*Call AJAX*/
  $('#{element.uniqueIdentifier}').change(function (event) {
  .... //Other code lines
  });
 });
</script>
```

When render the first value is replaced correctly but the next not and generate a syntax error in javascript. I have tried to use a variable for save value but in that case none fluid variable is replaced; and using `<![CDATA[ { ]]>` generate other error where escaped the javascript and show only variable.

I am using TYPO3 8.7.

Comment: Maybe a cache problem? Did you add second variable later? Try to delete all caches.

Comment: How does the generated JS look like? What is error message of the JS syntax error?  Even if the 2nd `{element.uniqueIdentifier}` is not replaced by fluid, it shouldn't generate a syntax error .. because the replacement takes place inside of a string literal.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling I have been delete caches in TYPO3 selector, from install tools and delete typo3temp folder content. But still not work

Comment: @qwertz the syntax error is: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{element.uniqueIdentifier}` for second time is not replaced

Comment: It make no sense, that fluid replace identical only once. A workaround can be to fill in a variable `var uniqueIdentifier = # + {element.uniqueIdentifier};`and use them in jQuery `$('uniqueIdentifier').date...`

Comment: I do not understand the behavior. Using the method of declare a variable, HTML render is the same that in Fluid template and not make the replace `var uniqueIdentifier = '#' + '{element.uniqueIdentifier}';` and this generate other syntax error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{element.uniqueIdentifier}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what happend, because many times works differents solutions as plain fluid keys (`{}`) or `<![CDATA`. In this case the other alternative that works was used the `f:format.raw` fluid tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#solicituddeAuditorios-repeatablecontainer-1_0_datetimepicker-2').datetimepicker();
  /*Call AJAX*/
  $('#<f:format.raw>{element.uniqueIdentifier}</f:format.raw>').change(function (event) {
    .... //Other code lines
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your code like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[var myUniqueElementIdentifier = "#" + ]]>{element.uniqueIdentifier}<![CDATA[;]]>
      $(function () {
        $(myUniqueElementIdentifier).datetimepicker();
        /*Call AJAX*/
        $(myUniqueElementIdentifier).change(function (event) {
          .... //Other code lines
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Using `<![CDATA` skip the all code between this strings and render only the fluid variable replaced `<script type="text/javascript">
solicituddeAuditorios-repeatablecontainer-1_0_datetimepicker-1
 </script>` , so it generates a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Numeric separators are not allowed at the end of numeric literals`